# How do i make "Unite" find my variable names?

Tags: r, tidyr, data-cleaning

I have a list of English classes från different time periods with the same contents. I wish to combine these classes into a single column.

I try writing:

```
test5<-unite(test5,"ENGELSKA",c("MARKEN200","MARKENGENG05","MARKEN1201"))
```

But for whatever reasons R can't find my columns, even though they're correctly specified. I would prefer not to resort to stating the column number (though this does work) since I'll need to use the "unite" command multiple times and since the use of index numbers seems to mess that up.

I have previously had to reshape the data and remove the resulting periods in the column name. Possibly, this has something to do with this. I have tried writing the column names with backticks and spaces as specified below, but to no effect.

Snapshot of data:

```
structure(list(`MARKEN200      ` = structure(c(8L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), .Label = c("A  ", "B  ", "C  ", "D  ", "E  ", "G  ", 
"MVG", "VG "), class = "factor"), `MARKEN1201     ` = structure(c(NA, 
NA, 8L, 7L, NA, 8L), .Label = c("A  ", "B  ", "C  ", "D  ", "E  ", 
"G  ", "MVG", "VG "), class = "factor"), `MARKENGENG05   ` = structure(c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA, 3L, NA), .Label = c("A  ", "B  ", "C  ", "D  ", "E  ", 
"G  ", "MVG", "VG "), class = "factor")), reshapeWide = list(
    v.names = "QUAL_RATING", timevar = "SEL_CRITERION", idvar = "PNR", 
    times = structure(3:1, .Label = c("BI   ", "BII  ", "HP   "
    ), class = "factor"), varying = structure(c("QUAL_RATING.HP   ", 
    "QUAL_RATING.BII  ", "QUAL_RATING.BI   "), .Dim = c(1L, 3L
    ))), row.names = c(1L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to solve this previously I surrounded the spaces+backticks with quotes. Once I tried the code with just backticks/spaces the code actually worked:

```
test5<-unite(test5,"ENGELSKA",c(`MARKEN200      `,`MARKENGENG05   `,`MARKEN1201     `))
```

I don't really approve of these column names but I can work with this for now.